# How to do a launch configuration where it runs a bash command in a specific folder location?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to configure VSCode to run all my python tests with a launch configuration (since I'm having a hard time getting it to successfully do a Test Discovery). I want to be able to just run `pytest ./` in my file location.

Something like this:

```
{
        "name": "Python: Run Tests",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "pytest",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "cwd": "C:\\path\\to\\tests\\folder",
        "args":["./"]
    }
```

I've tried using the full path to the pytest.exe but it doesn't recognize my packages in my test scripts:

[image]

Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: What is the command being executed to get the traceback above? Maybe copy the entire output to your post.

Comment: It's the same as the configuration there except the program attribute is pointing to where pytest is at in my computer C:\Users\spencer.sutton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pytest.exe

Comment: What did you use to convert to an `exe`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because you're misusing the [`"program"` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_program).

If you're simply looking for a way to execute your tests under pytest manually, you could either do that from the terminal directly or use a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks).

But test discovery should be working, so if it isn't then please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.